# How to compose date from first NSDate and time from second NSDate into one NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need one thing:

- create **one** output `NSDate` that includes both of them with format: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00"`, where `yyyy-MM-dd` is from first `NSDate` and `HH:mm:00` is from second `NSDate`

Comment: Did you try anything ? How did you get those two data ?

Comment: You write about having two output formats. You do not write anything about having two dates. There is a differences. Are the dates you have both strings?

Comment: `NSDateComponents` could be a way if they are `NSDate`, else if they are `NSString`, an append string and then the use of a `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: i have two buttons, one for date and one for time. When I tap one of them I have a popover and select the time or date (depends on type of button).

Comment: combine then into one string, and use the `NSDateFormatter` for get the `NSDate` instance from that string... where can you experience difficulties in this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by creating a convenience initializer, like this:

```
convenience init(date: NSDate?, time: NSDate?) {
    var combinedDate = NSDate()

    if let date = date {
        if let time = time {
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let timeComponents = calendar.components(.HourCalendarUnit | .MinuteCalendarUnit | .TimeZoneCalendarUnit, fromDate: time)
            var dateComponents = calendar.components(.YearCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
            dateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour
            dateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute
            dateComponents.second = 0
            dateComponents.timeZone = timeComponents.timeZone

            if let dateFromComponents = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents) {
                combinedDate = dateFromComponents
            }
        }
    }

    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate: combinedDate)
}
```

Basically it composes a date from components from two dates. For instance, it takes hours, minutes and seconds from the second `NSDate` called *time*, and year, month, and day from the first `NSDate` called *date*.

You can modify the components to make more or less accurate. You even extend the intializer to include customized units for the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Used this code

```
+ (NSDate *)combineDate:(NSDate *)date withTime:(NSDate *)time 
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    unsigned unitFlagsDate = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsDate fromDate:date];
    unsigned unitFlagsTime = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |  NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsTime fromDate:time];

    [dateComponents setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    [dateComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

    NSDate *combDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];   

    return combDate;
}
```

may help you

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version:

```
    init?(date: Date, time: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .timeZone], from: time)
    var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
    dateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour
    dateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute
    dateComponents.second = 0
    dateComponents.timeZone = timeComponents.timeZone

    guard let combined = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else { return nil }
    self = combined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two strings:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *outputDate = [dateformate dateFromString:[@"2015-09-01" stringByAppendingString:@"08:33:00"]];
```